# Access Kotlin Jooq generated sources in JAVA

Tags: java, kotlin, code-generation, jooq

I am using Jooq 3.14.7 version to generate Kotlin sources.
My code base has both Java and Kotlin class and we are transitioning to Kotlin.

I am able to access Jooq sources in Kotlin class like below (FetchBooks.kt)

```
import project.mobile.generated.databaseBook.tables.references.I_BOOKS;

....
 .select(I_BOOKS.BOOK_NAME)
```

**But** in Java classes I have to go like this below (FetchBooks.java)

```
import static project.mobile.generated.databaseBook.tables.references.TablesKt.getI_BOOKS;

....
 .select(getI_BOOKS().getBOOK_NAME())
```

This seems a pretty messy way in Java.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could patch the code generator to generate some annotations, such as [`@JvmField`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#instance-fields) for your various properties. There's currently no hook for such annotations, so this doesn't work out of the box. Patching will be necessary (or copy pasting the implementation of `JavaGenerator::generateTable` and patching only that).

However, I suggest generating your jOOQ code with the `JavaGenerator` until your code base is migrated completely to kotlin.